# Does the camera angle matter when rendering a model or 3d animation for unity

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, export, camera

I want to help someone with making a game, and since they dont need any programers i may as well help them with other things. But my problem is the camera angle, i think it will affect the model/animation because you would of only rendered that angle. So im kind of confused because im wondering if i should just send them the project. Even though he wants the volentiers to use maya, but then i saw, in the list of things he needed help a layout of export settings for BLENDER say that the settings have to be like that.

This is the link http://puu.sh/kn93D/61fc4326d6.png
And next to the link it said; If exporting from blender use these settings.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the camera viewpoint doesn't matter at all. What they're asking for is not an image. They're asking for the actual model.

You're thinking of sprites. Some games use sprites, which are individual images that are rendered for a certain number of viewpoints. The original StarCraft uses sprites for all the movable things.

Other games use actual 3D, which are animated in the game engine and can be viewed from any given perspective. StarCraft II and Fallout 4 use actual 3D instead of sprites.

Your thinking about "sending them the whole project" is on the right track, but they can't use the Blender file itself. They've asked for an FBX, which is a format for storing the whole 3D model, its textures, its UV maps, and some other things. It's a lot like an OBJ or PLY, if you're familiar with those. This will let them use the whole model in the game.

In this case, the camera that will be viewing the model is not in Blender, it's in the game. So the camera in Blender doesn't matter... just make sure you don't include it in the export ;-)

You should also definitely check out the B.SE chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

There are several folks there who are making games with Blender and might be able to help you with more specific questions that might not be appropriate for the actual site.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

When animating a sequence that will be used in a video, we can animate "to the camera" to get an animation that looks good from the camera but may look weird if seen from a different perspective. In most 3D games we don't get that luxury. Consider games like doom or quake, the camera is fixed to the user who can move around freely and see game characters and objects from every angle. In this situation you have to make an animation that looks good from every angle.

Some recent games are using 3D graphics but have a fixed camera that may only allow the user to pan around the scene. If this is the case then you could get the camera angle from the game developer as a reference, then animate to that camera angle.

Either way, the camera in blender is not relevant when exporting the model data, the camera will be set and controlled by the game engine. Even if you include the camera in the export, you can't expect it to be the camera used in unity.

Answer (score 1):

Blender's camera has nothing to do with it at all...Unity will only import it as an empty game object. In fact, if all you're doing is animation, there is no need to even have a camera in Blender! Also, because of what import settings he said to use (selected objects is disabled), there *shouldn't* be a camera because it would clutter stuff up in Unity. Furthermore, there shouldn't even be lights in Blender unless you absolutely need them (just stay in solid viewport) for the same reason.